# SVG images not displaying in SharePoint Online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, image

Anyone know how to enable rendering of SVG images in SP Online?

When I access the image directly, my browser offers a save dialog.

Simple to fix, if it weren't in the hosted version.

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem. Has anyone been able to make it work?